# How can I get location from background?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, location, background-process

My problem is:

Save the user's location every 1 minute and after 15 minutes, push it to the server once. My approach is to create an underground thread. After 1 minute, call the function to save into sqlite 1 time. But how to run the function every 1 minute, in case the application is in the background then how to handle it.

I found the plugin: [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch).
But it takes at least 15 minutes to run once.

Comment: You also need to get location every minute while the app is in background?

Answer (score -1):

I've try this and it's working foreground & background (but not terminated):
[background_location](https://pub.dev/packages/background_location)